# Installing setup using sudo in Python

Tags: python, installation, setup, sudo

I'm getting a strange output when trying to install `setup.py` for a project. Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
$ sudo python setup.py    
install/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/NAME
copying NAME/__init__.py -> build/lib/NAME
running install_lib 
creating /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site packages/NAME
copying build/lib/NAME/__init__.py -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/NAME
byte-compiling /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/NAME/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/projectname-0.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: I got a similar error: http://codepad.org/sr9fpK8f

Comment: @ZCJ The output says taht webtest is successfully installed. open ipython and try >>>import webtest, if it will successfully come out that means it is installed. :)

Comment: It doesn't say 'successfully installed' anywhere on the output of `sudo python setup.py install`; does the `writing ...` from line 10 mean that it's installed?

Comment: @ZCJ: can you try the following, start python prompt, write `import webtest` and try any command like `webtest.__package__`, if it works means it is installed properly, `NOTE` : it tries to resolve the dependencies of WebOb using http://webob.org, make sure it is accessible from your machine.